# How Can I Render Image Component First in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an image component called "Sidebar" in one file and a main content component, "Main" in another. I am rendering them both inside a another component in another file called "Search." The only problem is that because the image loads more slowly, the content of "Main" gets rendered behind "Sidebar". I know I'm supposed to use componentDidMount or componentWillMount or something, but I don't understand the React docs on how to use this since they don't provide example for these. Could someone please tell me how to do that with the following code?

Sidebar.jsx

```
export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style = {{display: 'flex',
                           flexDirection: 'row',
                           position: 'absolute',
                           top: 0,
                           left: 0}}>
                <BackgroundImage/>
                <Nav/>
                <Logo/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Main.jsx

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div style ={{height: 900, width: 900, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Search.jsx

```
export default class Search extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        console.debug('componentWillMount');
    }
    render() {
    return (
        <div style = {{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Sidebar/>
            <Main/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your middle code snippet is a repeat of Sidebar.jsx and not Main.jsx.  I'd also suspect the absolute positioning might be the trouble since that pulls the element out of the normal flow.  Can you recreate the issue in a JS sandbox like https://codepen.io/ and edit with the link?

Comment: @gvfordo looks like Jessie fixed it.

Comment: I did not fix it but I corrected the error in my post. I will post on codepen. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I am unable to recreate the issue bc codepen doesn't seem to allow image uploads. I tried taking out the position absolute but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot without seeing the issue in action.  You can try referencing a random external image just to demonstrate.    Also,  try using just a plain div with dimensions and a color and see if it's really the image loading causing problems or if it's the css / layout.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this and not sure which one of these did the trick, but apparently I also had position: 'absolute' in another file that was screwing things up, so I took that out and then used flexBox in the Search page to render components in a row. Thanks for the help!